# Return returns undefined but console returns value

Tags: javascript, algorithm, variables, recursion

Algorithm for the recursive sum of all the digits in a number.
Example: 942  -->  9 + 4 + 2 = 15  -->  1 + 5 = 6.

Could someone tell me why there is a correct sum in the console when i print it by console.log but when i want to return there is undefined?

```
let sum = 0;

const sumOfDigits = (num) => {
  let number = num.toString();

  if (number.length > 1) {
    sum = 0;
    [...number].forEach((digit) => {
      sum += Number(digit);
    });
    sumOfDigits(sum);
  } else {
    console.log(sum);
    return sum;
  }
};

console.log(sumOfDigits(942));
```

Comment: you should return sumOfDigits(sum) when you call the recursion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont return the value for all the calls

Change `sumOfDigits(sum);` to `return sumOfDigits(sum);` like below

```js
let sum = 0;

const sumOfDigits = (num) => {
  let number = num.toString();

  if (number.length > 1) {
    sum = 0;
    [...number].forEach((digit) => {
      sum += Number(digit);
    });
    return sumOfDigits(sum);
  } else {
    console.log(sum);
    return sum;
  }
};

console.log(sumOfDigits(942));
```